# copy contenteditable HTML to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making an HTML reader inside HTML (For reasons...)

I used to be able to do this fine. I took the value of a text area and applied it to an iframe, like this:

```
    var x = document.getElementById("HTMLdocument");
    var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
    if (y.document)y = y.document;
    y.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById('page').value;
```

But there was something to do with style (The textarea did NOT like the background-attachment:local; property) So I had to change it to a div with `contenteditable` and here is my new code:

```
    var x = document.getElementById("HTMLdocument");
    var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
    if (y.document)y = y.document;
    y.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById('page').textContent;
```

But only basic HTML copies over to the iframe... how do I fix this? No html copies over if I use the .innerHTML instead of the .textContent. It's annoying. One thing is always wrong...

**Native JavaScript (For reasons and purposes)**

Comment: what is `basic HTML`? Without seeing a demo I have only eyes on your question

Comment: No style. So say you have <p style="color:red">Foo</p>, no color is applied... and script won't run either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xoqofu/5/edit)***

use `innerHTML` to get the whole inner HTML String:

```
document.getElementById('page').innerHTML;
```

that will take the complete `Paragraph` out of your elementwith al lthe related styles:

```
<div id="page" contenteditable>
    <p style="color:red">Foo</p>
</div>
```

```
var x = document.getElementById("HTMLdocument");
var y = (x.contentDocument || x.contentWindow);
if (y.document) y = y.document;

// Might work in Chrome but will fail in Firefox
// y.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById('page').innerHTML;

// So rather:
y.open();
y.write( document.getElementById('page').innerHTML );
y.close();
```

Comment: That broke it even more... now it wont even recognize the HTML code: if I put <p>TEST</p> it writes to the iframe <p>TEST</p> rather than TEST

Comment: The deal is, when I had a textarea, I had styles (inline and not) and script all copy to the iframe with no issue, but the background image would not stay local in firefox. I thought it would be a simple solution to make it a div with contenteditable. But no.